# Run multiple https enabled services on docker containers on same host Machine

Tags: docker

I want to run multiple services on port  443 on same host Machine in docker containers. Can I achieve this using multiple VirtualIp's without getting errors like bind address already in use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537849/docker-swarm-mode-multiple-services-same-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537849/docker-swarm-mode-multiple-services-same-port)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the host to have multiple services hosted from the same port (443), I would suggest using a reverse proxy such as HA Proxy and exposing that on host port 443 and then have it route to the appropriate backend.